# JSON Serializing date in a custom format (Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value)

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, fasterxml

```
could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String 
value '2012-07-21 12:11:12': not a valid representation("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

passing json request to REST controller method in a POJO class.user should enter only in below datetime format other wise it should throw message.why DateSerializer is not calling?

```
add(@Valid @RequestBody User user)
{
}
```

json:

```
{
   "name":"ssss",
   "created_date": "2012-07-21 12:11:12"
}
```

pojo class variable

```
@JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
@Column
@NotNull(message="Please enter a date")      
@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created_date;

public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    logger.info("serialize:"+value);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    logger.info("DateSerializer formatter:"+formatter.format(value));
    jgen.writeString(formatter.format(value));
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have the same problem, so I write a custom date deserialization
with `@JsonDeserialize(using=CustomerDateAndTimeDeserialize.class)`

```
public class CustomerDateAndTimeDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser paramJsonParser,
            DeserializationContext paramDeserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String str = paramJsonParser.getText().trim();
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Handle exception here
        }
        return paramDeserializationContext.parseDate(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing this CustomerDateAndTimeDeserialize class?

Answer (score 54):

Annotate your `created_date` field with the `JsonFormat` annotation to specify the output format.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = TimeZone.getDefault(), locale = Locale.getDefault())
```

Note that you may need to pass in a different Locale and TimeZone if they should be based on something other than what the server uses.

You can find out more information in [the docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html).

Comment: Is it all you have to do? I tried this and it didn't work by itself. Maybe some other annotations are required somewhere?

Comment: You need to be using Jackson: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html

Comment: Be aware of using this annotation. Here is known **[issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31822877/2650174)** with with one day less.

Comment: Don't forget to add timezone = "Canonical_ID_of_your_timezone" parameter after "pattern" if you want to have a right time. Timezones names could be found here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

Comment: Or use:   @Pattern(regexp = Constants.REGEX)

Answer (score 2):

For someone ,If you are using DTO/VO/POJO to map your request you can simply annotate your date field

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date customerRegDate;
```

And json request should be:

```
{
"someDate":"2020-04-04 16:11:02"
}
```

You don't need to annotate Entity class variable.

Comment: what if date is blank?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to bind a `JSON` string to date, this process is called `deserialization`, not `serialization`.
2. To bind a `JSON` string to date, create a custom date deserialization, annotate `created_date` or its setter with

   `@JsonDeserialize(using=YourCustomDateDeserializer.class)`

where you have to implement the method `public Date deserialize(...)` to tell Jackson how to convert a string to a date.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to have a custom Date object which takes care of its own serialization.

While I don't really think extending simple objects like `Date`, `Long`, etc. is a good practice, in this particular case it makes the code easily readable, has a single point where the format is defined and is rather more than less compatible with normal `Date` object.

```
public class CustomFormatDate extends Date {

    private DateFormat myDateFormat = ...; // your date format

    public CustomFormatDate() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomFormatDate(long date) {
        super(date);
    }

    public CustomFormatDate(Date date) {
        super(date.getTime());
    }


    @JsonCreator
    public static CustomFormatDate forValue(String value) {
        try {
            return new CustomFormatDate(myDateFormat.parse(value));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String toValue() {
        return myDateFormat.format(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the below steps.

1.In entity class annote it using @JsonDeserialize

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table")
public class Table implements Serializable {
// Some code
@JsonDeserialize(using= CustomerDateAndTimeDeserialize.class)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="created_ts")
private Date createdTs
}
```

2. Write CustomDateAndTimeDeserialize.java [Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27007894/3336921)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to annotate with the `@JsonFormat` and afterwards, this is working well:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
private java.util.Date expDate;
```