# Why is Spring JPA translating a valid date into an unrecognizable formatted String?

Tags: spring, rest, http, datetime, jpa

I set up a Spring Microservice app with a POST endpoint which takes in a RequestBody object which contains a 'java.util.Date' field. From my other app, when I send a request to this POST endpoint, the Date in the JSON looks good, in the format "2019-06-20T13:33:47.487-07:00", but when my microservice receives the request, it converts the Date String into the following: "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM" and tells me "Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM": not a valid representation".

I've played around with different annotations, including "@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)" and "@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)". Also tried setting JSONFormat manually, but that isn't a fix, since the input date string is getting reinterpreted somehow somewhere.

Here's the microservice POST endpoint:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/orders/create")
public ResponseEntity createOrder(@RequestBody final HubOrder hubOrder) {
    List<OrderLineitem> orderLineitem = orderService.hubOrderToOrderLineitems(hubOrder);
    repository.saveAll(orderLineitem);
    return ResponseEntity.created().build();
}
```

And bean:

```java
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class HubOrder {
    private BigInteger id; 
    private Date created; 
    private String lastModifiedBy; 
    private List<HubLineitem> lineitems;
}
```

And I hit the endpoint from my app like so:

```java
HubOrder hubOrder = createHubOrderFromOrder(order);
Gson gson = new Gson();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8888/orders/create");
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(hubOrder));
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();


request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Where hubOrder.getCreated() == "2019-06-20T13:33:47.487-07:00"

The error from my microservice is "2019-07-08 20:50:47.663  WARN 2400 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM': Unparseable date: "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM"); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM': Unparseable date: "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM")
"

Comment: create a custom `deserializer` and try using single format if possible. and have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655532/json-serializing-date-in-a-custom-format-can-not-construct-instance-of-java-uti

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out why it's deserializing wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to annotate your `Date created` field in `HubOrder` with the following;

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa")
private Date created
```

Deserialization expects in different formats by default depending on configuration, and it seems your locale affects it, as described [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/281). To customize the behaviour, you'd have to utilize the above annotation. Or to apply this for all cases do the following;

- either instantiate gson with the pattern as follows;

  ```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
      .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
      .create();
  ```
- or pass a custom adapter for `Date` types

  ```
  public class GsonDateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>,JsonDeserializer<Date> {

      private final DateFormat dateFormat;

      public GsonUTCDateAdapter() {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
      }

      @Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date,Type type,JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
          return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
      }

      @Override public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement,Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
        try {
          return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
      }
  }
  ```

  then

  ```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                 .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateAdapter())
                 .create();
  ```

Comment: Tried this, but getting "Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jun 20, 2019 1:33:47 PM": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";"

Comment: Debugging the POJO that gets sent as the body, created="2019-06-20T13:33:47.487-07:00"

Comment: Debugging might use default `.toString()` which might not be what the original value is in raw JSON, which seems to be different as you've shared...

Comment: I added an extra doublecheck where I do "Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(lineItem.getCreated().toString());"

Comment: In that case it works, but I wanted to try to fix the date format becoming like that automatically in my microservice...

Comment: @TDaddy The problem was when you try to serialize the result with `gson.toJson(hubOrder)`, here it was mapping to that pattern somehow, maybe it was configured that way? You can try to control that with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format). You can set `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` as the default pattern for gson, thus it would work properly I think...

Answer (score 1):

you should write function setCreated() and see the input, after that using jsonFormat to convert it :D